# Science Fiction Short Story Identification about humans begrudgingly allowed to join a galactic mindnet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short I read a few years ago about humans joining a galactic mindnet/telepathic network. The other members(some are more resistant than others) allow the humans to join. Some time later, one of the mindnet member species lashes out unprovoked against the humans through the mindnet, a telepathic attack. The remaining humans that survive cut themselves off from the mindnet and the entire race dedicates itself to revenge. They find their revenge by launching endless physical fleets to their enemies.

It's written from the perspective of one of the aliens on the network that wanted the humans to join initially. They remark that their race is one of the few that humans don't seek revenge against.

It is not Guardian Angel.

Themes: Endurance, Resilience, Inter-species conflict, inter-galactic conflict, War, Revenge

Comment: Was it specifically called the "*mindnet*"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. I remember it was a telepathic network of multiple alien species but I don't remember if it had a specific name or not. (I think it was called mindnet thought)

Comment: OK. How many is "a few years"? Can you recall anything about the storyteller (name, species, type of alien)? What weapons did the humans attack the aliens with? How short was it? Was it likely to have been read in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: I assume this is [you](https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/3l4mc3/request_looking_for_a_short_story_about_humans/). You might want to mention in your question that you've already ruled out "Guardian Angel" by Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: Ah yes that is me. 
I read the story 3-4 years ago among many famous short stories like The Last Question, They're Made of Meat, etc. It was on a plain website where each story had its own page and there were about a dozen stories, that site appears to have been taken down since I couldn't find it again.

Comment: More details: The humans were seen as inferior by a lot of species prior to their joining. The humans were attacked unprovoked. They attacked back with huge(slow but relentless) fleets of ships in a campaign lasting many millennium.

Comment: Can you remember anything about the site that you read it on?

Comment: Sadly, nothing more than I have already said.